# Google Analytics how to track level-up in a Game efficiently?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I would like to track and understand user behaviour related to level-up.

1. What metric should I be interested in collecting?
2. In which way will allow me to do so, and minimize hits ?

Context: The Game style is Poker, and user can level up only after a Hand is finished and anytime in that session.

1- Right now I'm collecting **Level-up event** and **number of hand played** in that level,

```
getAppTracker().send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("COMPLETIONS")
            .setAction("Level-up")
            .setLabel(Integer.toString(level))
            .setValue(1)
            .build());
```

Comment: I have never heard of using Google Analytics other than for website analytics. Are you sure your using the right tool for the job? Also what are you exactly trying to learn from your data? It seems your just collecting your data for the sake of it.

Comment: Yes you can use Google Analytics for Mobile (Android& iOS), The objective behind it to understand what level the user find it difficult and leave.

Comment: No I know that you can use GA on mobile, but that GA is the best tool to find what level the user finds difficult?

Comment: This is absolutely possible. You can create a custom metric to gauge which levels receive more (or less) level-up events. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

Comment: @nyuen I saw that but it's missing clear implementation and beside GA for web is bit different from mobile. @ Yahya Uddin I think so, by collecting at what level users count drops will help me to find out... Do you have a # view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use custom dimensions or/and metrics for these purposes.
In the Google Analytics documentation article [about custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) in the "Examples" section you may found example for the tracking of game levels. Hope this technique will help you to track user behavior in your poker game